# Parallel.ForEach Loop with Retry Logic in C#

Tags: c#, concurrency, parallel.foreach, retry-logic

I am using `Parallel.ForEach` to download multiple files in C# from google bucket to folder location. I'm  using retry logic so it can retry downloading files in case files download fails during downloading. How can I apply retry logic for each file or each thread in `Parallel.ForEach` loop.

```
Parallel.ForEach(listFiles, objectName =>            
{
    retryCount = 0;                        
    countOfFiles++;
    downloadSuccess = false;
    bucketFileName = Path.GetFileName(objectName.Name);
    guidFolderPath = tempFolderLocation + "\\" + bucketFileName;

    while (retryCount < retryCountInput && downloadSuccess == false)
    {
        try
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(guidFolderPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write);
            using (fs)
            {                                               
                storage.DownloadObjectAsync(bucketName, objectName.Name, fs, option, cancellationToken, progress).Wait();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception occured while downloading file: " + ex.ToString());                   
            Thread.Sleep(RetryInterval(retryCount, minBackoffTimeSpan, maxBackoffTimeSpan, deltaBackoffTimeSpan));
            retryCount++;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly

Comment: It seems you have created your own retry mechanism. Does not it work?

Comment: Your code would probably work if you just set downloadSuccess to true after download

Comment: You shouldn't use `Parallel.ForEach()` for IO bound work. Create a list of tasks and `await Task.WhenAll(list)` them. The `Thread.Sleep(` does it all. You're blocking threadpool threads.

Comment: Sharing `bucketFileName` across threads feels like a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Above code in working fine in case of foreach loop. When I'm using Parallel.ForEach loop to download multiple files, then this code is failing to retry per file.

Answer (score 1):

I would change it to tasks and use the async. This way your Thread.Sleep doesn't block a threadpool thread. The Parallel.ForEach is for CPU bound work.

Something like:  *(I'm unable to compile/test this without the rest of your code)*

```
int retryCountInput = 5;
var tasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (var file in listFiles)
{
    var task = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        // make it local
        int retryCount = 0;
        string bucketFileName = Path.GetFileName(objectName.Name);
        string guidFolderPath = tempFolderLocation + "\\" + bucketFileName;

        while (retryCount < retryCountInput)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var fs = new FileStream(guidFolderPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
                    // Use await here, instead of `Wait()` so this threadpool thread
                    // can be used for other tasks.
                    await storage.DownloadObjectAsync(bucketName, objectName.Name, fs, option, cancellationToken, progress);

                break;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception occured while downloading file: " + ex.ToString());

                // Use Task.Delay here, so this thread is 'released'
                await Task.Delay(RetryInterval(retryCount, minBackoffTimeSpan, maxBackoffTimeSpan, deltaBackoffTimeSpan));
                retryCount++;
            }
        }
    });
    tasks.Add(task);
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Hi @Jeroen, I have modified my code and removed parallel.foreach instead using foreach loop to iterate through files. But now, I'm not able to find all files in downloaded path. No of downloaded files in download path changes and this behavior seems random. can I use Task.run for IO operations?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified my code and removed `Parallel.ForEach` instead using `foreach` loop to iterate through files. But now, I'm not able to find all files in downloaded path, though logs shows all files got downloaded. Number of downloaded files in download path changes and this behavior seems random. Can I use `Task.Run` for I/O operations?

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var objectName in listFiles)
{
    var task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        downloadSuccess = false;
        bucketFileName = Path.GetFileName(objectName.Name);
        guidFolderPath = tempFolderLocation + "\\" + bucketFileName;

        var maxRetryAttempts = 3;
        var pauseBetweenFailures = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
        RetryHelper.RetryOnException(maxRetryAttempts, pauseBetweenFailures, async () =>
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(guidFolderPath, FileMode.Create,
                FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write);
            using (fs)
            {
                var progress = new Progress<IDownloadProgress>(
                    p =>
                    {
                        DownloadProgress(p, retryCount, objectName.Name);
                    });

                await client.DownloadObjectAsync(bucketName, objectName.Name,
                    fs, option, cancellationToken.Token, progress);
            }
        });
    });
    tasks.Add(task);
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Yes, you can certainly use `Task.Run` for I/O operations. The recommended pattern in this case is to pass an async delegate as argument, like it's done in Jeroen van Langen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61055858/11178549). What is not clear in your code is the signature of the `RetryHelper.RetryOnException` method. If it returns a `Task`, then you are supposed to `await` this task, otherwise it will run in fire-and-forget fashion.

Comment: RetryHelper.RetryOnException doesn't return task. It has void return type.

Comment: What about its third parameter? Is it of type `Func<Task>`? If not, you have an [`async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) there.